# Why output is printed in asci code instead of integer ?dart

Tags: console, dart, output, flutter

I don't know why output is printed in ascii code instead of integer value ,what wrong with my code ?

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int n = 0;
  print("input: ");

  do {
    n = stdin.readByteSync();
  } while (n>1000 || n<0);

  if (n % 4 == 0) {
    print("output: ");
    print(n);
    n++;
  } else {
    print("output: ");
    n--;
    print(n);
  }
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Can you instead of a screenshot, add your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value as `String` using [`stdin.readLineSync()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html) then [`parse`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/int/parse.html) it to `int` like below:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int n = 0;
  print("input: ");

  do {
    n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  } while (n>1000 || n<0);

  if (n % 4 == 0) {
    print("output: ");
    print(n);
    n++;
  } else {
    print("output: ");
    n--;
    print(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: the output is showed correctly after i used int.parse .Thank you for the  explanation

Answer (score 2):

Paste your code so it can be easier to help you.
I could have given you a fixed source code if you would have provided.

Instead, I'll try to explain:
Your stdin will be provided as a string, you read it as bytes so `5` will be come `35` as hex.
When you print it, my guess is that it will automatically be converted to a decimal value *(53, and the output shows 52 because `53 % 4 = 1` and then to decrease with `n--` before printing it so it become `52`)*.
Those numbers like you said of the [ASCII Table](http://asciitable.com). 
In order to fix it, make sure you have the string representation of the input (stdin). Then convert the value to integer: `"2".toInt()`

Edit:
I could have easily find the complete solution,
You need to get the stdin as a string first: [readLineSync](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html) and convert it to int:

```
n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
```

Note: Code not tested, but it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: `String` doesn't have a `toInt()` instead use `int.parse()`